# NetHack tiles mode on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, nethack

NetHack 3.6.0 was released in Dec 2015. An [official binary](http://www.nethack.org/v360/ports/download-mac.html) is available for Mac OS X, but it's terminal-only.

[NetHackCocoa](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nethackcocoa/id528223360), which has brought so much joy to so many, has, alas, not been updated since 2012 as far as I can tell.

Is there any way to play NetHack 3.6.0* using a tile set on Mac OS X?

* An optimist might say "NetHack 3.6.0 *or greater*, but that seems awfully optimistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fellow mac user: I have found a solution!

Some kind person on github named MaddTheSane has ported Cocoa to 3.6.0 and OS X 10.5+.

[Here is the repo](https://github.com/MaddTheSane/NetHack-Mac-OS-X).

Note: Nethack 3.6.1 is currently under development, so I'm not sure how well this repo will hold up with that.

To install this, just unpack and build the repo.  Detailed instructions (which albeit are the same for building 3.6.0 as far as I can tell) are in the README.

Comment: Interesting. This is probably beyond me: "just unpack and build the repo". For now I'll continue to wait for a binary build. But for other readers this may provide a solution.